# react_devtools_backend.js:4012 No routes matched location "/about" and PostId and Post

Tags: reactjs, react-router

В файле `rout.js` внес пути к файлам

```java
export const routes = [
    {path: '/about', component: About, exact: true },
    {path: '/posts', component: Post, exact: true},
    {path: '/posts/:id', component: PostId, exact: true},
]
```

Через `map` создаю `route` и всю инфу передаю в пропс, но так не работает

```java
<BrowserRouter>
     <div className="navbar">
         <div className="navbar__items">
             <Link to ="/about">about</Link>
             <Link to ="/posts">posts</Link>
         </div>
     </div>

<Routes>
     {routes.map(item => {
         <Route
             element = {item.component}
             path = {item.path}
             exact = {item.exact}
         />
             console.log(item.compon)
      })}

Изначально был написан этот код и он работает
{/*<Route path="/posts" element={<Post/>}/>*/}
{/*<Route exact path="/about" element={<About/>}/>*/}
{/*<Route exact path="/posts/:id" element={<PostId/>}/>*/}
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Ошибка указывает на то, что маршруты не совпадают с местоположением "/about" и PostId и Post, поэтому они не могут быть обработаны.

Comment: Но ниже то я такие же пути прописал, что в одном варианте "/posts" и в другом также. Или я что-то не так понимаю)                                                                                                                                       element = {item.component} тут получается element = '/posts' и коде ниже тоже самое и он работает

Comment: Для начала исправьте опечатку и проверьте. В вашем .map замените ex**e**ct на ex**a**ct

Comment: exact исправил, тоже обратил внимания, но путь не появился). В чем-то другом ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В массиве, ключу component должен быть назначен JSX элемент, а не функция.
При возврате JSX из map стоит использовать обычные скобки **()**, если компонент возвращает 1 значение в виде одной строки.

Если строк кода больше чем одна, то надо использовать фигурные скобки и указывать явно return

```
export const routes = [
    {path: '/about', component: <About />, exact: true },
    {path: '/posts', component: <Post />, exact: true},
    {path: '/posts/:id', component: <PostId />, exact: true},
]

<Routes>
    {routes.map(item => (
        <Route
          element = {item.component}
          path = {item.path}
          exact = {item.exact}
        />
      ))}
</Routes>
```

Пример, когда в map более 1 строки

```
<Routes>
    {routes.map(item => {
        console.log(item.path)
        return <Route
          element = {item.component}
          path = {item.path}
          exact = {item.exact}
        />
      })}
</Routes>
```

Comment: Спаибо большое..работает